# Control flow for looking for object and stopping once object found

Tags: python, nested-loops, control-flow

I have a camera rig where I initialise the stages and need to then move the camera and find the range over which an object is detectable. I cannot predict where the object is going to be. If no object detected by camera I increment the camera stage and look again. When I find the position where the object starts to be detectable I append the current camera location to a list. I repeat this over the whole range. What I would like to do is stop the unnecessary attempts to look for an object once it is no longer within view, i.e. once it stops being found.
I have thought of a list which might read like:
y_list = [100,150,200,250,300,...500] and I couldn't figure out how to check if the list had stopped growing in length for a few iterations of the for loop. I thought of using another list to show when an object had been detected but don't know how to implement it.

y_list_flags = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

**Code**

```
y_list = []
len_y = len(y_list)

for i in list(range(1,70):
    my_obj = obj_present()#returns True if object detected, False otherwise
    if my_obj:
        y_list.append(current_cam_position)
        move_cam_stage()
    elif my_obj not True:
        move_cam_stage()
```

**Desired output**

```
y_list = [100,150,200,250,300, 350,400,450,500,550,600] # list stops growing when object not found and test has stopped
```

or

```
y_list = [100,150,200,250,300, 350,400,450,500,550,600] # list stops growing when object not found and test has stopped a few attempts after drop is no longer found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `move_cam_stage` and `obj_present` are dummy functions.

loop break and list stops growing when object not found again.

code:

```
def move_cam_stage():
    print("move cam stage")

def obj_present(i):
    y_list_flags = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
    return y_list_flags[i] == 1

y_list = []
for i in range(1,70):
    my_obj = obj_present(i)#returns True if object detected, False otherwise
    if my_obj:
        y_list.append(50 + 50*i)
        move_cam_stage()
    else:
        if len(y_list)>1:
            break
print(y_list)
```

result:

```
move cam stage
move cam stage
move cam stage
move cam stage
move cam stage
move cam stage
move cam stage
move cam stage
move cam stage
move cam stage
move cam stage
[450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950]
```